# How to Reduce Thread.sleep() Latency in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, concurrency, latency

I am generating timing events in a loop in a (non-UI) thread in an Android application, and I need those events to occur at precise intervals in time, (precise here means not varying any more than +/- 5 millisecs). Any errors of +/-10 millisecs (and certainly +/- 20 millisecs) can be perceived by the user.  At the top of this loop I do some other calculations that take a variable amount of time, but at the bottom of the loop, I need the event to occur at a pre-calculated time.

A higly simplified version (without exception handling) of one attempt at my non-UI thread is below:

```
public final void run() {

    long loopTime = 2500L;
    long eventTime = (System.nanoTime() / 100000L) + loopTime;

    while (true) {

        calcutionsTakingVaryingAmountOfTime(); // takes 200 millisecs or less

        long eventWait = eventTime - (System.nanoTime() / 100000L);
        Thread.sleep(eventWait / 10L);
        listener.onEvent();

        eventTime = eventTime + loopTime;
    }
}
```

It is the call to `listener.onEvent()` that needs to be precisely timed.

In the example above, the timing variables `loopTime`, `eventTime`, and `eventWait` measure time in tenths of a millisec. The expressions `(System.nanoTime() / 100000L)` measuring current time are likewise in tenths of a millisec.

I am absolutely certain that `calcutionsTakingVaryingAmountOfTime()` *always* takes less than 200 millisecs, and the call to `listener.onEvent()` is just a few millisecs. So as it stands, with `loopTime` set to `2500L`, my events ought to occur every 250 millisecs.

I have intstrumented my code (not shown) to print to `Log.d()` the latency in the `Thread.sleep()` wake up time. That is, I calculate

```
long latency = (System.nanoTime() / 100000L) - eventTime
```

immediately after the return from `Thread.sleep()`, and print it to `Log.d()`.

When I run this in the emulator, what I find is that `latency` (after dividing by 10 to get the result into millisecs) is normally jumping between 1 and 50 millisecs in successive passes through the loop, with occasional values as high as a half a second. When run on an actual device, things are quite a bit better, but still a little wobbly (and even still, the emulator behavior makes me wonder if this is going to happen on users' devices).

To try to steady my event and control the latency, I tried several other approaches:

- In replaced the `Thread.sleep(eventWait / 10L)` call, with a call to `this.wait(eventWait / 10L)` (a completely inappropriate use of wait(), I know)
- I manipulated the thread priorities prior to entering the loop, calling `Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO)` like is done all over the android libraries

But there was no improvement at all in the latency with these.

The one approach that steadys the event, and reduces the latency to *less than 2 or 3 millisecs*, and rarely hiccups is to replace the `Thread.sleep()` call by a polling loop:

```
while ((System.nanoTime() / 100000L) < eventTime)
    ;
```

On the one hand, I feel embarrassed spending machine cycles like a drunken sailor on liberty. On the other hand, I am beginning to think there is no better way, and I should burn the machine cycles in the polling loop to reduce my latency, and meet my specification. Of course, when my app goes to the background, I pause my thread, so this polling loop works. But what a waste.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using delayed messages with `Handler` for similar purpose. It can be little overkill. In you case I would take a look to `Timer` class.

```
mTimer = new Timer();
mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.v("TEST", " tick");
    }
}, 0, 250);
```

This gives me latency +-2 millisecs at emulator.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried a couple of things. First, I tried to use a call to 'java.util.Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)' as a (more or less) drop in replacement for my call to 'Thread.sleep()'. It went something like

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried a couple of things. First, I tried to use a call to 'java.util.Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)' as a (more or less) drop in replacement for my call to 'Thread.sleep()'. Then I tried using 'scheduleAtFixedRate()' like yours. In both cases, I have from 1 to 70 millisecs latency on the emulator, though latency is nearly in spec on a device. Is there anything else you are doing to get your +/-2 millisecs latency on the emulator?

Comment: I were running only tiny test app, so there was almost none stress. My CPU is Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T9300  @ 2.50GHz.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is useful to me.

Comment: @singerofwords: I have the very same problem as you. `Thread.sleep()` ruins my app, because I also have latencies precisely as big as you describe. But how did you simulate the `Thread.sleep` with the `Timer`? Did you already find a better solution?